# Citing "Academic Editor" in Journal Article

Tags: citations

MDPI lists "academic editors" for some of their papers, e.g.:

[image: Screenshot of bibliographic information from an MDPI paper that reads: Citation: Wen, Y.; Chen, H.; Wei, X.; Li, K.; Liu, F.; Liu, X. Examining Predictors and Outcomes of Decent Work among Chinese Female Pre-Service Primary School Teachers. Sustainability 2023, 15, 730. https://doi.org/10.3390/su15010730 Academic Editor: Gazi Mahabubul Alam]

Is this name to be reproduced in the bibliography when using common citation styles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, the answer is no. I should however add that every journal can have their own policy for references and you should read it whenever you submit something.

Answer (score 3):

Academic editors don't contribute to the paper's contents (not directly anyway), so no - you do not reproduce their name when citing the article. For comparison, you never give the name of the editor-in-chief of the cited paper's journal when citing the article, either.

Comment: Interesting. I've been told to cite editors of proceedings, for example. Also editors of collections.

Comment: @mritz_p Proceedings are not articles, however; they are a collection of articles, and which articles are included in the proceedings is decided by the editors. So editors do affect the contents of proceedings directly.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is given by MDPI themselves on the corresponding [article website](https://www.mdpi.com/2071-1050/15/1/730) (see section "Share and Cite", scroll to bottom):

> **MDPI and ACS Style** 
> Wen, Y.; Chen, H.; Wei, X.; Li, K.; Liu, F.; Liu, X. Examining Predictors and Outcomes of Decent Work among Chinese Female Pre-Service Primary School Teachers. *Sustainability* **2023**, *15*, 730. https://doi.org/10.3390/su15010730

> **AMA Style** 
> Wen Y, Chen H, Wei X, Li K, Liu F, Liu X. Examining Predictors and Outcomes of Decent Work among Chinese Female Pre-Service Primary School Teachers. *Sustainability*. 2023; 15(1):730. https://doi.org/10.3390/su15010730

> **Chicago/Turabian Style** 
> Wen, Ya, Huaruo Chen, Xindong Wei, Kai Li, Fei Liu, and Xia Liu. 2023. "Examining Predictors and Outcomes of Decent Work among Chinese Female Pre-Service Primary School Teachers" *Sustainability* 15, no. 1: 730. https://doi.org/10.3390/su15010730

So no, the academic editor name of a journal article is not to be reproduced in the bibliography when using common citation styles. A citation style requiring that would be rather unusual.

I do not know from where exactly you got your example, but, although the formatting does not reflect this, it seems to me that what is listed after "**Citation**" ends with the doi. The "Academic Editor" would be a separate piece of information, then.

Comment: The example is from the PDF of the article (left column).